# convert matlab function to python: dynamic mode decomposition

Tags: python, function, matlab

I have a Matlab function to convert to python:

```
function [mpK,mpV,mpD] = mpEDMD(G,A)

G=(G+G')/2; % make sure G is Hermitian
[VG,DG]=eig(G);
Gsqrt=VG*diag(sqrt(diag(DG)))*VG'; % G^{1/2}
GsqrtI=VG*diag(sqrt(1./diag(DG)))*VG'; % G^{-1/2}

[U,~,V] = svd(GsqrtI*A'*GsqrtI);
[mpV,mpD]= schur(V*U','complex'); % schur usedto ensure orthonormal basis

mpV=GsqrtI*mpV;
mpK=GsqrtI*V*U'*Gsqrt;
mpD=diag(diag(mpD));

end
```

I have written this python code:

```
    G = (G + G.conj().t() )/ 2

    # Compute the eigendecomposition of G
    DG, VG = torch.eig(G,eigenvectors=True)
    DG = DG[:, 0]  # Extract the real part of eigenvalues

    # # Compute G^{1/2} and  G^{-1/2}
    Gsqrt = torch.mm(torch.mm(VG, torch.diag(torch.sqrt(DG))), VG.t())
    GsqrtI = torch.mm(torch.mm(VG, torch.diag(1.0 / torch.sqrt(DG))), VG.t())

    # # Compute SVD of GsqrtI * A * GsqrtI
    U, S, V = torch.svd(GsqrtI @ A.T @ GsqrtI)

    # # Ensure orthonormal basis using Schur decomposition
    mpD,  mpV = torch.eig(V @ U.T,eigenvectors=True)

    mpV = GsqrtI @ mpV
    mpK = GsqrtI @ V @ U.T @ Gsqrt
```

But I am not getting the same results.
Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: could you share the expected result and the actual result?